# diseño div img con css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular2-template

Tengo el siguiente diseño:

[image: Invernadero]

Tengo que añadirle una serie de iconos y label con datos. Es una pequeña interfaz gráfica de la domotica en un invernadero.

Tengo dos dudas de como hacerlo:
He puesto la imagen del invernadero de background en una div con posicion relativa y dentro las div con los iconos y label con posicion absolute, el problema es el siguiente:

1º ¿Como puedo hacer que esta imagen del background se haga mas pequeña o grande dependiendo de la pantalla que visualice esto?

2º ¿Como puedo hacer que los iconos y label este siempre en una posición respecto a la imagen del bacground, aunque hagamos la pantalla mas pequeña o grande? Ahora mismo en mi monitor de 27 esta bien, pero al cambiarlo al de 13 se solapa todo.

Estoy usando Angular4, boostrap4, css.

```css
.invernadero {
  background-image: url(/assets/img/greenhouse.png);
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.media {
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  position: absolute;
}

.media2 {
  margin-top: 27%;
  margin-left: 38%;
  position: absolute;
}

.media3 {
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 57%;
  position: absolute;
}

.media4 {
  margin-top: 27%;
  margin-left: 52%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="invernadero">
  <div class="media">
    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="assets/img/temp.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4>55ºC</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="media media2">
    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="assets/img/temp.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4>55ºC</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="media media3">
    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="assets/img/hum.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4>55ºC</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="media media4">
    <img class="d-flex mr-3" src="assets/img/hum.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4>55ºC</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: para el 1 puedes mirar background-size
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp Tambien puedes ponerlo como imagen IMG y las capas de media utilizar z-index para el punto 2 yo utilizaria left, right, top, bottom en lugar de margin-left, margin-top .... Creo que tambien puedes utilizar para todo un gráfico svg y modificar por javascript cuando quieras que cambie, incluso propiedades por CSS
Hay muchos ejemplos, busca animación SVG Por ejemplo https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu primera pregunta, te paso una clase css para que la imagen de fondo se adapte al tamaño de la pantalla:

```
.imgContainer {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px; left: 0px;
   width: 100%; height:100%;
   background-image: url('la_ruta_de_tu_imagen');
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Ahora, para la segunda pregunta, te sugiero que a los elementos que quieras que siempre mantengan una posición los pongas "absolute" con relación a su padre y la ubicación de estos elementos dentro del padre sea gestionado por la propiedad css llamada "margin". es decir, que un elemento tenga:

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: 5px;
```

Y con eso el elemento siempre estará 5 pixels a la izquierda, se haga grande o pequeño el padre.